# "UnboundLocalError" When I try to use the tkinter Frame widget in python3?

Tags: tkinter, widget, python-3.3

```
master = Tk()
title_frame = Frame(master, bg="yellow")
Label(master, text="Sample Name").pack()
master.mainloop()
```

When I try to use this code inside of a class method I get an error message stating "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Frame' referenced before assginemt". I'm not sure how to fix this. The first time I ran this it worked fine, and then I tweaked some things in the code below these lines and it started giving me that error message. Interestingly about 10 lines down I create a frame in the exact same manner and it does not appear to raise an error messages.

Comment: Does this function create a local variable named `Frame`? Please show the full function that gives this error.

Comment: The indentation looks wrong, but without more context, I can't be sure what is right.

Comment: 'class method' (meanding 'takes class rather than instance as first parameter') should probably be 'instance method' or just 'method'.  Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @BryanOakley no, it doesn't python

Comment: What does "it doesn't python" mean? All I was asking is if the code happened to have a local variable named `Frame` somewhere in the code. I've seen people make this very common mistake, and doing so will yield this exact error message.